# Delete logging object

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a script that runs periodically, but it also seems to be setting up the logging object without it being removed. This caused multiple entries of the same logging message, with 1 extra entry each time it is run. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `logging.removeHandler(logging.handlers[0])` to remove the existing logging handler each time the script ends